# How to capture the PID of a process when launching it from command line?

Tags: process, cmd, pid

Is there a way to do this purely in a .bat file?

The purpose is to launch `iexplore.exe`, then kill just that instance when it's finished.

Comment: Just for the record: DOS doesn't have PIDs. If you mean the Windows command-line environment, then say so, but please don't mark everything as DOS which comes in 16-color fixed-width fonts ...

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I use:

```
@echo off

rem there is a tab in the file at the end of the line below
set tab=    
set cmd=javaw -jar lib\MyProg.jar
set dir=%~dp0

echo Starting MyProg
set pid=notfound

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=;=%tab% " %%i in (
    `wmic process call create "%cmd%"^, "%dir%"`
) do (
    if /I %%i EQU ProcessId (
        set pid=%%j
    )
)

echo %pid% > MyProg.pid
```

The directory is set to the directory that the cmd file is located in.  Change `dir` to alter that.  Modify `cmd` to change which command is run.

If you want a stop.cmd that kills it, it would look like this

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in (%~dsp0MyProg.pid) do taskkill /F /PID %%i
del %~dsp0MyProg.pid
```

Comment: I just tried the wmic call on windows 7 and it works.  It's possible that the parsing of the result is going wrong somehow, I'll check later.

Comment: @kybernetikos Thanks! Worked out of the box. This saved me a lot of effort!

Comment: A more cleaner solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51353994/12705489

Answer (score 3):

you can use vbscript, here's an example creating notepad, then terminating it using its pid

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")
Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
errReturn = objProcess.Create("notepad.exe", null, objConfig, PID)
If errReturn = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Process ID is: " & PID
End If 

WScript.Echo "Ready to kill process: " & PID & "? [Y|y]"
Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfLine
   strInput = strInput & WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
Loop
If LCase(strInput) = "y" Then
    WScript.Echo "Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessId = '" & PID & "'"
    Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where ProcessId = '" & PID & "'")
    For Each objProcess in colProcessList
        objProcess.Terminate()
    Next
End If
```

save as myscript.vbs and on command line

```
c:\test> cscript /nologo myscript.vbs
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on the answer provided by @kybernetikos since it has a parsing issue. Note the line `if %%j gr 0 (`

```
@echo off

rem there is a tab in the file at the end of the line below
set tab=    
set cmd=javaw -jar lib\MyProg.jar
set dir=%~dp0

echo Starting MyProg
set pid=notfound

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=;=%tab% " %%i in (
    `wmic process call create "%cmd%"^, "%dir%"`
) do (
    if %%j gtr 0 (
        set pid=%%j
    )
)

echo %pid% > MyProg.pid
```

Answer (score 2):

Most often you do know what task you start - in this case, which page iexplorer shall show.

So how about

```
taskkill /FI "Windowtitle eq *yourpagetitle*"
```

It will kill all instances of something showing your page title, but with a specific title most often there should be exactly one.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Ummm, [TaskList](http://techtaxi.blogspot.com/2004/01/tips-tricks-using-dos-commands-on.html) & [TaskKill](http://www.computerhope.com/taskkill.htm)?!

Comment: so I have 7 Iexplore processes up, and launch another one. How do I capture that PID as I launch it?

Comment: Can't you do a TaskList before you launch it and after, diff them and get your PID? -- I know this isn't the easiest way, but I don't know of a nice way of doing it with just some regular Windows scripting.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason your approach of getting process id did not work for me, but since I'm expert in batches, I've coded my own approach, attaching here:

```
@echo off

call:AsyncCmd
rem call:AsyncCmd "echo hello world"
rem call:AsyncCmd "call build.bat"
exit /b

rem ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rem Starts asynchronous command execution 
rem %1 is command, if empty - only aborts existing build.
rem ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:AsyncCmd
if exist %~dp0SetupBuild_Completed.txt (
    del /f %~dp0SetupBuild_Pid.txt >nul 2>&1
    del /f %~dp0SetupBuild_Completed.txt >nul 2>&1
)

if not exist %~dp0SetupBuild_Pid.txt goto lStartProc
    rem --------------------------------------------------
    rem Abort build process
    rem --------------------------------------------------
    set /p pid=<%~dp0SetupBuild_Pid.txt
    echo Cancelling setup build process, process id %pid%
    pskill -t %pid%
    del /f %~dp0SetupBuild_Pid.txt >nul 2>&1

:lStartProc
if "%~1" == "" exit /b 0

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem Starts asyncronous build process
rem --------------------------------------------------
set dir=%~dp0
set dir=%dir:~0,-1%
for /f "tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in ('wmic process call create "cmd /c mincon.exe && %~1 && echo 1>%~dp0SetupBuild_Completed.txt"^, "%dir%" ^| findstr /r "ProcessId"') do set pid=%%a
echo Setup build started, process id: %pid%
echo %pid%>%~dp0SetupBuild_Pid.txt
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell can be used for this:

```
powershell -executionPolicy bypass -command "& {$process = start-process $args[0] -passthru -argumentlist $args[1..($args.length-1)]; exit $process.id}" notepad test.txt

echo Process ID of new process: %errorlevel%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do that with simple command line utilities, as IE actually spawns child processes for each tab, i.e. if IE is not yet running you would get one parent IE process and a child process for the tab, and if IE is already running you would simply get a single child process.

It will be even quite tricky when you write your own tool to kill IE because when you kill a child (tab) process, IE will automatically recover this tab.

See also this related question: [How to obtain process of newly created IE8 window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568093/how-to-obtain-process-of-newly-created-ie8-window) (though there is no good answer there).

Comment: we're still stuck with IE6 here! So they're all on separate processes - but I thought later tabbed versions still used processes behind the scenes.