# Terminate a batch file w/ another batch

Tags: file, batch-file, termination

Does anyone knows how to kill a batch file w/in another batch file?

Scenario:
batch file #1 is running (or looping) in the background. While #1 is on the background, a separate (not w/in batch file #1) batch file is activated manually with a code inside killing batch file #1.

It's like the opposite of call (I guess).

Is this possible and how?

Comment: See the accepted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807794/how-to-capture-the-pid-of-a-process-when-launching-it-in-dos)

Answer (score 1):

`Taskkill` Command can end a process

`Tasklist` Command will list out all the process

Also you may use `find` command to find the process that wanted to kill

Answer (score 0):

You can kill a batch file from another batch by querying the window title.
See this blog for more info: http://dotnetcrunch.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/kill-batch-file-script/