# PID of last running process in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to grep the the PID of last running process in Windows. I am running the command in the background.

- start "Window Title" /b "c:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -i
  1 -w file1.pcap
- start "Window Title" /b "c:\Program
  Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe" -i 1 -w file2.pcap

How do I get the PIDs of these commands?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly by tracking them.

When you start the first instance, you could use the `tasklist` command with the filter by the image name (see `tasklist /?`) to find the PID, which you would then store somewhere. (The output of `tasklist` can be parsed with the `FOR /F` command, see `FOR /?` for more info.)

Then, when you run the second instance, you do the same, but additionally filter out the stored PID (for example, using `FIND /V`, see `FIND /?` for more help), so you get only new instance's PID. Store it as well to use later like the first one when you need to run a third instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use wmic to launch the processes and get the pid from that.  I've posted what I use for this as an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616359/412335).