# Close browser after calling it

Tags: batch-file

I have a series of batch files that execute some action on a windows server, and then call a web url that registers on a database that the actions are completed and when.

I call the web file like this
`Start "http://the_url"`

It works fine, but i noticed that the browser persist in the background processes, but if I log in with the user there's no opened browser's window.

Ho can I close the browser in the same batch file? There's a better way to call an url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start the process with `WMIC` to get its pid:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=5 tokens=2 delims==; " %%a in ('wmic process call create "chrome.exe url" ') do (
    set "pid=%%a"
    goto :break
)
:break
echo %pid%
taskkill /pid %pid% /f
```

May be better approach is to execute directly a webrequest without a browser.
Check [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) which is capable to execute numerous kind of http requests.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need the Process ID of the Browser to kill it. This might prove problematic if another browser is already open when the `Start` command is executed. However it is possible by iterating over the output of `tasklist` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9489666/16959). Once you have this Process ID(PID) you can call [`taskkill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) to end it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting a browser, you might be able to just use a Powershell command such as:

`powershell Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://the_url/"`

If performing a GET on the URL is the only thing required, this should do the trick.