# How to start a windows process in git-bash with a name

Tags: windows, bash, git, cmd, process

I want to start a java app from git bash **in a new window** with a process name.
In win cmd it is simple `start "appname" java -jar /path/to.jar` for example.
But in git bash I get an error `The system cannot find the file javaapp`

Sidenotes

- windows 10 environment
- I use git bash as my primary terminal because of the unix commands available there and because of the git repository status visible inside the prompt.
- The main reason for naming the process is that I have a shell script that starts multiple java apps, and a shell script to kill them all. For the kill part I need the PID of that process
- I followed this great tutorial on [springhow.com](https://springhow.com/start-stop-scripts-for-spring-boot-applications/) but in that the process is not started in the new window and if I try to use `start` it gives the wrong pid (not the pid of the java app) so I tried the solution in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51319981/418031) but it does not work in bash

If it helps, this is the script (mainly inspired from the link above) to start instances:

```
#!/bin/bash

#------ DECLARATIONS
app_path=./target/1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
pidFile=./pid.file
instances=1

#------ BUILD IF NEEDED
if [ ! -f $app_path ];
then
    echo Building project...
    mvn clean package
else
  echo Using existing project build
fi

#------ UPDATING INSTANCES COUNT FROM PARAM IF PRESENT
if [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
    instances=$1
fi

echo Starting "$instances" "$app_path" instances

#------ CLEARING PID FILE
> $pidFile

#------ STARTING INSTANCES
for (( i = 0; i < instances; i++ )); do
    start java -jar $app_path &
    echo $! >> $pidFile
done

echo NOTES:
echo "  " Process ids for "$app_path" instances stored in "$pidFile"
echo "  " To stop instances type Ctrl+C on each or run stop_multi_apps.sh script that will stop processes with ids from "$pidFile"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cmd for this.

```
cmd.exe /c start \"appname\" "app"
```

You do not need `&` in this case because cmd's `start` starts does not wait gor it.

If you want to start your program in git bash you could do something like the following:

```
cmd.exe /c start \"appname\" "C:\path\to\git\bash -c <command>"
```

Comment: I tried in git bash to run `cmd.exe /c start "appname" java -jar /path/to.jar` but it just switches the terminal to win cmd and does not run separate window with the app

Comment: @Zavael you have to use backslashes and `"`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: its weird, I had to use double slash for the `/c` parameter to accept the command... this one finally worked `cmd.exe //c start \"appName\" java -jar target/app.jar` but it started a cmd window with `\appName\ ` instead of `appName`

Comment: I've experianced the same result but I wasn't able to fix this.

Comment: good to know, until better answer comes up, your answer is partialy correct