# close powershell window from batchscript

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want to close powershell window after my batch script completes execution.
This is my batch script. I tried exit command but it is closing only command prompt.

```
     @ECHO OFF
     setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

     start PowerShell.exe -Command help

     powershell.exe -command exit
```

I want to close powershell window from my batchscript. Which command I am missing?

Comment: What's wrong with just `@PowerShell -Command help`?

Comment: Your last command opens a new powershell process and doesn't interact with the first one. Assuming you are using a batch/cmd you could kill the powrshell process by its PID, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486960/how-to-get-pid-of-process-just-started-from-within-a-batch-file for a few ways to do this.

Comment: IAM actually reading the help of powershell to a file and do some processing. The powershell window should be open during this processing . Once the batch file completes this processing I want to close the powershell window at the end from the batch script. I am unable to do that. I got stuck there.I tried getting $PID and closing the window but this is not closing the powershell window.

Comment: If you want the batch file to wait for the PowerShell task to complete, why not invoke it directly, synchronously from your batch file? To that end, simply omit `start`.

Answer (score 3):

Kindly use below code in your CMD prompt to kill the existing PowerShell window.

```
taskkill /IM "powershell.exe" /F
```

Comment: This will kill _all_ PowerShell processes, which may be undesired.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple commands on the same line are separated by a SEMICOLON `;`.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "help; exit"
```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Yes, but note that if you use `-Command`, the session _automatically_ exits after execution of the command(s). That is, the OP's sample command wouldn't actually keep the process alive - `-NoExit` would be needed for that.

Comment: I am actually copying the help of powershell to a file and doing some processing in the batch file. After all this script runs, I want to close the powershell window at the end from my script.I could close the cmd prompt by using exit but the powershell window is staying alive. I want to close powershell window . This is where I got stuck.

Comment: @codewarrior - What happens if you simply take off `start`? The PowerShell command will run and it will exit.