# How can I halt execution of my python script until a subprocess is going on?

Tags: python, batch-file, process, subprocess, batch-processing

I have the following usecase where I am creating a batch file `run.bat` which will initiate another batch file `command.bat`, is there anyway I can halt the script execution until the inner `subprocess` is going on.

- I have tried methods like creating a file at the start of my parent `subprocess` and delete at the end, but inner process will be in a separate thread so it didn't help.
- Also tried extracting process id of the batch file and check if it exists in `'tasklist'` and as long as it is there exeuction will be stopped , once it will be stopped there then execution conitnues back again, but here i am getting `process_id` of parent `subprocess` only which didn't help as well, i am  not able to get the id of the inner one.

  ```
   def check_process_exists(pid_to_check):
    try:
        output = os.popen('tasklist').read()

        print(output)
        pids = []
        lines = output.splitlines()
        for line in lines[1:]:
            parts = line.split()
            if len(parts) >= 2:
                pid = parts[1]
                pids.append(pid)
        process_ids = [item for item in pids if item.isdigit()]
        process_ids = [int(item) for item in process_ids]
        print("process",process_ids)
        for pid in process_ids:
            if pid_to_check == pid:
                print("process found")
                return True
        print("not found")
        return False

    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False






   def create_run_bat_file(self):
    """
    Create run.bat file with additional commands to create and delete a text file.
    """
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    filename = "{}_{}".format(self.job_name, timestamp)
    text_file_path = os.path.join(os.environ["Temp"], "{}.txt".format(filename))
    # Define the run.bat file path
    run_bat_file = os.path.join(self.loc_path, "run.bat")

    # Create the run.bat file
    with open(run_bat_file, "w") as fid:
        fid.write('@echo off\n')
        fid.write('echo Process Holder > "{}"\n'.format(text_file_path))
        fid.write('start /B CMD /C "Q:/..../CPAU.exe %~dp0\\command.bat"\n')
        fid.write('ping 127.0.0.1 -n 2 > nul\n')
        fid.write('del "{}"\n'.format(text_file_path))
        fid.write('pause\n')

    return run_bat_file, text_file_path


   def create_command_bat(self):
    # Create a common command.bat file
    cmd_bat_file = "%s/command.bat" % self.loc_path
    with open(cmd_bat_file, "w") as fid:
        line = "@echo off\n"
        line += 'robocopy "{}" "{}" '.format(self.src_path, self.dst_path)
        if self.op_type == "move_dir":
            line += '/MOVE /S /E'
        elif self.op_type == "copy_dir":
            line += '/S /E'
        elif self.op_type == "copy_file":
            line += self.file_name
        else:
            # Handle unsupported operation types here
            pass
        fid.write(line)

   def execute(self):
    self.create_user_copy_dir()
    update_log_file("\n created user_copy: %s" % self.loc_path)

    # Create the single command.bat file
    self.create_command_bat() #cmd_bat_file = 

    run_bat_file, log_file_path = self.create_run_bat_file()
    # cpauprocess_pid = self.get_cpauprocess_pid()
    process = subprocess.Popen(run_bat_file,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    process_not_done = check_process_exists(pid)
    while process_not_done:
        process_not_done = check_process_exists(pid)
    print("Process is finished")
  ```

is there any alternate way such as extracting `process_id` of inner batch process, or something which I am missing, such as I can stop the execution unless process is completed.

Any help would be really great , Thanks & Regards

Comment: I'm a little confused on your wording but if you just need to wait for your `process = subprocess.Popen` command to finish you can just do `process.communicate()` afterwards and the script will wait for the subprocess to complete before proceeding.

Comment: Actually I am calling a subprocess on a bat file , but if you see the bat file which i am using from subprcess which is run.bat is executing another bat file which is command.bat, so process.communicate won't work , as in this one issue can happen which is command.bat will be keep on executing and the subprocess might already finish, I want to wait as long as command.bat is executing.

Comment: could you either (a) log the PID of the command.bat to a file somewhere when it's first triggered and read that file then check using your current method or (b) have the run.bat wait until command.bat is done to complete and use process.communicate()?

Comment: yep thats what i am trying to do , extract the pid of the command.bat and will store it in a file, and then will keep on checking until the process is in tasklist, if you could help me with that it would be great tho.

Comment: I think that would likely be done as a step in your run.bat file. I'm not familiar with with batch but this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486960/how-to-get-pid-of-process-just-started-from-within-a-batch-file) may help with capturing your PID for command.bat.

Answer (score 0):

If you already are using python, I don't really see a reason to be using batch or VBS. It's slower and harder to maintain, so, as a recommendation, you should try to only use Python. Python surely can do everything batch can in a safer, more maintainable, and secure way, you wouldn't be losing.

Alas, you don't exactly need to find the PID for it to accomplish your goals, too, if I understood them correctly. There are a couple of approaches you could take:

- You can use the `start /WAIT` command in your parent batch file to
  make it wait until the child batch file has completed execution.
- As you are using Python, you could use subprocess.run() instead of
  subprocess.Popen(). The run() function is blocking, which means it
  won't return until the child process has completed.
- You can also get the child process ID and monitor it to see when it's
  done, but this would make the code maybe excessively complex for no
  reason.
- As a last resort, you can use a semaphore file. Create a file in the
  child process at the beginning and delete it at the end. The parent
  process can then loop and wait until the semaphore file is deleted.
  This is very common and a very poor solution, but it works.

### Modifying the Batch File:

```
start /WAIT CMD /C "Q:/..../CPAU.exe %~dp0\\command.bat"
```

or

```
start /B /WAIT CMD /C "Q:/..../CPAU.exe %~dp0\\command.bat"
```

This will pause the execution of the parent batch file until `CPAU.exe %~dp0\\command.bat` has completed execution. This seems like the easiest solution for your problem.

### Using Python `subprocess`:

```py
subprocess.run([run_bat_file], shell=True)
```

That way, the code will wait for it to run in order to continue, which may be of your desire if not using `Popen` is not a dealbreaker to you.

### Check Child Process ID:

```py
    import psutil

    parent_pid = psutil.Popen([run_bat_file], shell=True).pid
    parent = psutil.Process(parent_pid)

    while parent.is_running():
        for child in parent.children(recursive=True):
            if child.status() == psutil.STATUS_RUNNING:
                # Do something or just wait
                pass
```

By importing `psutil`, you make this approach way easier, as it's a good library for doing so.

### Semaphore File

For this approach, you would have to modify your code to create a file, may it be in the current working directory `%cd%` or in a fixed one, like `%TEMP%`, and, after conclusion, it should be deleted.

Being so, before the execution of the batch file, you should create something like `stop.txt` in python and loop with a millisecond waiting until it finds there is no `stop.txt` anymore, which, of course, would be deleted by the batch file.

Choose the method that aligns best with your current setup.