# Batch file to run close file if already running (scheduled job)

Tags: java, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

So I've run into an interesting problem, where I made a program in java that seems to have crashed once.  I don't know the exact conditions that caused it to crash (since it seemingly stopped logging for that period of time).  However it is being called via a batch file (that runs:

```
java -jar MyProg.jar
```

)

With that said, when the program failed to execute properly (despite some amount of safety nets in place) it stopped running when it should have.   Is there some way that I can check to see if user x is running java.exe, and if they are, do a:

```
taskkill /IM java.exe /f
```

Before I try to run my program or something similar?   Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I understood it correctly but if you are asking to see the process and close them so in windows it can be done via task manager - processes tab.

Comment: I'm looking to do this programmatically since the task will run every 5 minutes even when I'm away / asleep.   As a result it would need to detect if the program is running as username ____________ (it's a system account that only runs this one thing) and if it is, kill it before running the jar file.

Comment: Are you asking how to kill a task that was started by a particular user using taskkill?

Comment: @MartinWilson essentially.  Assume I wanted to kill "Java.exe" but only if it were opened by user DBell whenever I'm running my batch file.

Comment: How about storing the pid in a file when you start the process and then using that to kill it later? Capturing the pid is the hard part. There are a few ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807794/how-to-capture-the-pid-of-a-process-when-launching-it-in-dos/11616359#11616359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq java.exe" | find /i "java.exe" >nul && taskkill /im java.exe /f || rem Java not running, run your program
```

Comment: Unfortunately this might not be the best way to do things, since there are multiple system accounts running their respective programs on this box at different intervals.  I know that there's at least 1-2 other accounts that run 5-minute tasks that use java.  I would need to first find out that my account (let's say DBell) was calling java.exe to run,  is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not that I know of, I don't think tasklist has filters for what user is running the process. Unless you knew what session ID you were, then you might be able to do it.